# Is it good to use a static EF object context in an MVC application for better perf?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let's start with this basic scenario:

I have a bunch of Tables that are essentially rarely changed Enums (e.g. GeoLocations, Category, etc.)  I want to load these into my EF ObjectContext so that I can assign them to entities that reference them as FK.  These objects are also used to populate all sorts of dropdown controls. Pretty standard scenarios so far.

Since a new controller is created for each page request in MVC, a new entity context is created and these "enum" objects are loaded repeatedly. I thought about using a static context object across all instances of controllers (or repository object).

But will this require too much locking and therefore actually worsen perf?

Alternatively, I'm thinking of using a static context only for read-only tables. But since entities that reference them must be in the same context anyway, this isn't any different from the above.

I also don't want to get into the business of attaching/detaching these enum objects. Since I believe once I attach a static enum object to an entity, I can't attach it again to another entity??

Please help, I'm quite new to EF + MVC, so am wondering what is the best approach.

Comment: Very interesting question, and probably one that is going to keep me awake very late tonight investigating if this can be done.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I never have any static Context stuff, etc. For me, when i call the database (CRUD) I use that context for that single transaction/unit of work.

So in this case, what you're suggesting is that you wish to retrieve some data from the databse .. and this data is .. more or less .. read only and doesn't change / static.

Lookup data is a great example of this.

So your Categories never change. Your GeoLocations never change, also.

I would not worry about this concept on the database/persistence level, but on the *application* level. So, just forget that this data is static/readonly etc.. and just get it. Then, when you're in your application (ie. ASP.NET web MVC controller method or in the global.asax code) THEN you should cache this ... on the UI layer.

If you're doing a nice n-tiered MVC app, which contains

- UI layer
- Services / Business Logic Layer
- Persistence / Database data layer

Then I would cache this in the Middle Tier .. which is called by the UI Layer (ie. the MVC Controller Action .. eg. public void Index())

I think it's important to know how to seperate your concerns .. and the database stuff is should just be that -> CRUD'ish stuff and some unique stored procs when required. Don't worry about caching data, etc. Keep this layer as light as possible and as simple as possible.

Then, your middle Tier (if it exists) or your top tier should worry about *what to do with this data* -> in this case, cache it because it's very static.

Comment: Thx for answering, Pure.Krome.
That is a good solution IF I can use the cached Categories EntitySet as references in my other EF context calls. But I can't. If EF worked like Linq2SQL (or EF 4.0 with FK Association), then I can simply use the PK IDs and that's end of story. But unfortunately I can't do that at this point. I have to assign a valid Category to parent entities for creation/update calls within the relevant EF context. This sucks, but is the way you are "supposed" to use EF... So if I were to use EF like this, how best to "cache" these data like Categories?

Comment: If i read you right, what you're trying to do is either 1) eager load some static lookup data and/or 2) lazy load some static lookup data. In my opinion, i turn _OFF_ lazy loading. I personally hate that. Why? It's means u haven't thought about your application and have not loaded all the data with the initial hit ... which is bad IMO. Less db hits the better. So, if u need some object which contains a child property .. which is some lookup data .. then maybe we can figure this out. So, can u post some code please, so I can then try and manipulate it. I can't promise anything .. but lets see..

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something similar using Linq2SQL by retrieving these 'lookup tables' as lists on app startup and storing them in ASP's caching mechanism. By using the ASP cache, I don't have to worry about threading/locking etc. Not sure why you'd need to attach them to a context, something like that could easily be retrieved if necessary via the table PK id.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is as much a question of what to cache as how.  When your are dealing with EF, you can quickly run into problems when you try to persist EF objects across different contexts and attempt to detach/attach those objects.  If you are using your own POCO objects with custom t4 templates then this isn't an issue, but if you are using vanilla EF then you will want to create POCO objects for your cache.

For most simple lookup items (i.e numeric primary key and string text description), you can use Dictionary.  If you have multiple fields you need to pass and back with the UI then you can build a more complete object model.  Since these will be POCO objects they can then be persisted pretty much anywhere and any way you like.  I recommend using caching logic outside of your MVC application such that you can easily mock the caching activity for testing.  If you have multiple lists you need to cache, you can put them all in one container class that looks something like this:

```
public class MyCacheContainer
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> GeoLocations { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The next question is do you really need these objects in your entity model at all.  Chances are all you really need are the primary keys (i.e. you create a dropdown list using the keys and values from the dictionary and just post the ID).  Therefore you could potentially handle all of the lookups to the textual description in the construction of your view models.  That could look something like this:

```
MyEntityObject item = Context.MyEntityObjects.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
MyCacheContainer cache = CacheFactory.GetCache();
MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel { Item = item, GeoLocationDescription = GeoLocations[item.GeoLocationId] };
```

If you absolutely must have those objects in your context (i.e. if there are referential entities that tie 2 or more other tables together), you can pass that cache container into your data access layer so it can do the proper lookups.

As for assigning "valid" entities, in .Net 4 you can just set the foreign key properties and don't have to actually attach an object (technically you can do this in 3.5, but it requires magic strings to set the keys).  If you are using 3.5, you might just try something like this:

```
myItem.Category = Context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
```

While this isn't the most elegant solution and does require an extra roundtrip to the DB to get a category you don't really need, it works.  Doing a single record lookup based on a primary key should not really be that big of a hit especially if the table is small like the type of lookup data you are talking about.

If you are stuck with 3.5 and don't want to make that extra round trip and you want to go the magic string route, just make sure you use some type of static resource and/or code generator for your magic strings so you don't fat finger them.  There are many examples here that show how do assign a new EntityKey to a reference without going to the DB so I won't go into that on this question.