# Best practice for persisting database-stored lookup data at app level in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Slogging through MVC+EF and trying to focus on doing things the right way. Right now I'm looking to add a dropdown to a form but I'd like to avoid hitting the database every time the page loads so I'd like to store the data in the app level.  I figure creating an application level variable isn't the best approach.  I've read about using the cache and static utility functions but surprisingly, nothing has sounded terribly definitive. (Static classes bad for unit testing, caching bad

So I have two scenarios that I'm curious about, I'm not sure if the approach would differ between the two.

1) A basic lookup, let's say the fifty states.  Small, defined, will never change. Load at application startup. (Not looking for a hard coded solution but retrieval from the database.)

2) A lookup that will very rarely change and only via an admin-like screen.  Let's say, cities/stores where your product is being sold. So data would be stored 
in the model but would be relatively static unless someone made changes via the application. So not looking to hit the database every time I need to populate a dropdown/listbox.

Seems like basic stuff but it's basically the same as this topic that was never answered:

[Is it good to use a static EF object context in an MVC application for better perf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990876/is-it-good-to-use-a-static-ef-object-context-in-an-mvc-application-for-better-pe)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I will address you question in a few parts.  First off, is it inherently bad to use static variables or caching patterns in MVC. The answer is simply no.  As long as your architecture supports them it is OK.  Just put your cache in the right place and design for testability as I will explain later.

The second part is what is the "right" way to have this type of persisted data stored so you don't have to make round trips to the DB to populate common UI items.  For this, I don't recommend storing EF objects.  I would create POCO objects (View models or similar) that you cache.  So in the example of your 50 states you might have something like this:

```
public class State
{
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would do something like this to create your cached list:

```
List<State> states = Context.StateData.Select(s => new State { Abbreviation = s.Abbreviation, Name = s.Name}).ToList();
```

Finally, whatever your caching solution is, it should implement an interface so you can mock that caching method for testing.

To do this without running into circular references or using reflection, you will need at least 3 assemblies:

Your MVC application
A class library to define your POCO objects and interfaces
A class library do perform your data access and caching (this can obviously be split into 2 libraries if that makes it easier to maintain and/or test)

That way you could have something like this in your MVC code:

```
ICache myCache = CacheFactory.CreateCache();
List<State> states = myCache.ListStates();
// populate your view model with states
```

Where ICache and State are in one library and your actual implementation of ICache is in another.

This is what I do for my standard architecture: splitting POCO objects and interfacees which are data access agnostic into a separate library from data access which is the separate from my MVC app.

Comment: Technically you could put your POCO classes the interface for your caching mechanism in your data access layer.  Then you *could* implement caching in your MVC app and implement the interface and just pass it in to the data access layer like this: dataLayer.LoadStates(myCache) where ICache would expose a property or method to let you populate the list of states.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a Dependency Injection tool such as unity, ninject, structuremap, etc. These will allow for the application level control you are looking for by implementing a kernel which holds on to objects in a very similar way to what you seem to be describing.

Comment: I'm using Ninject in my project. But I didn't think that DI had to do with caching data at the application level. Am I wrong on that?